# How do I stop the identify results popup window in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, popup, identify, results

I use the identify tool in QGIS3 a lot. When I click a feature it show the results in a identify panel and it gives a popup window that shows the results.

I want to get rid of the popup window as it obscures my view. It also opens a new window for every click which means I end up with a lot of popup windows.

I am on QGIS 3.2.3 but I have encountered this problem with other versions as well.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using QGIS 3.10, you may click on the small wrench-icon in the icon-panel at the top of the identify-tool window (see screenshot). Make sure the (only) option is deactivated.

[image]

The [documentation for 3.4](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify) suggests, there is a checkbox somewhere, you can uncheck. I suggest you upgrade your QGIS and then use the method described above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do not have the same wrench icon. Upgrading is difficult as it is a remote computer. Not my own laptop.

Comment: @PythonStudent did you have a look at the documentation I linked?

Comment: I was having the same problem using QGIS 3.10.1 on a MAC and do not have the wrench icon either. There is however a small chek-box at the bottom of the identifytool window that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enlarge the identify window by dragging down its bottom edge until you see the X in the red box on the top upper right of the enlarged window.  Click on the X to dismiss the window.